# Adding two terms in a Simultaneous Equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, gaussian-elimination

Sorry, but I have a problem where I must add two terms like this in a simultaneous equation:

```
2x + 4y = 32
2x - 3y = 11
```

I want to add the terms `4y` and `3y`, because they are different signs. If I do it I get `y`. I checked my answer and my answer was wrong. It will only be correct if the sum of the two terms are `7y`. And in the book, there was a solved example that was solved this way with the signs ignored and they were just added.

I think the sum must be `y` because `4y + -3y` = `4y - 3y` = `y`. Why is that?

Sorry, I am studying for my exam tomorrow.

Comment: The sum of the two terms *4y* and *3y*

Comment: If you add as you suggest then, yes, you do get $y$. But you also get $4x$, which is not useful. If you _subtract_ the equations rather than add them you will make the $x$ terms cancel. That's a good thing. And then you do indeed get $7y$. I'm quite sure the book did not "ignore the signs".

Comment: Yes, I just forgot. it is `-3y`

Comment: The `x` term is canceled. In simultaneous equations, if the sign is the same, we subtract, if it is not, it will be added. I think we only use the signs for deciding which arithmetic to use. and it is not used in the real calculation. So I am only talking about the `y` term, just ignore the `x` term.

Comment: I think I got it now, with some brainstorming, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to subract, rather than add to get rid of $\space x.\space $ In general, you want to add/subtract terms or multiples of terms so that one-or-more variables cancel.

\begin{align*}
  2x + &4y = 32\\
-(2x - &3y = 11)\\
&\overline{7y=21}\\ 
\implies &\space \space y=3
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\\
 2x + 4(3) &= 32\\
\implies 2x &=32-12\\
\implies x&=10\\
\\
          2x - 3(3) &= 11\\
\implies  2x  &= 11 +9\\
\implies x&=10\\
\end{align*}